# How can I remove windows.dll reference in my project? (I know how to remove normal dlls, just the windows doesn't work )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference

I added windows reference in my project, however, later I want to remove it but cannot do it. Other references can be deleted or removed using the normal (right click or optimize or remove unused references). I'm wondering if this has anything to do with retarget?
[image]

Comment: Please post  a screenshot of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain see teh update, I want to remove that Windows reference, thx

Comment: What kind of project is your project. Is it a Universal App or a Portable Class Library?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it is a portable class library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `Windows` reference is part of the Portable Class Library when you target "Windows" as one of your PCL targets. If you want to remove it you will need to go in to the project settings and remove the "Windows 8" or "Windows 8.1" target.

[image]

Comment: Just one thing, I did it without removing the windows 8.1 but add the .NET Framework 4.5.1 to solve  this problem. Thank you. This answer should work too.